# What does HTML.Raw do?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Is `HTML.raw()` specific to MVC? On what scenarios we have to use it?

Can you please explain with an example.

Comment: Check it out: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Text output will generally be HTML encoded.  Using Html.Raw allows you to output text containing html elements to the client, and have them still be rendered as such.  Should be used with caution, as it exposes you to cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

Comment: "Used with caution", meaning trust the HTML doesn't do anything to the page that you don't want done or [sanitize](https://www.google.com/search?q=sanitize+html+.net) it to your standards before passing it to Html.Raw.

Answer (score 9):

[HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) MSDN

> Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted
>   as HTML markup.

Answer (score 8):

**Html.Raw**

- Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted as HTML 
  markup.

**For Example :**

**Controller**

```
public actionresult Htmlraw()
{
viewbag.message = "Hey friends lets go" + "<br />" + "for chillout";
return view();
}
```

**index view**

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.message);
```

**output**

hey friends lets go

for chillout

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is specific to MVC.

It writes unencoded HTML to your page.
Most other methods HTML-encode a string when you write it to the page.