# <br /> inside <div> tag wont work MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got problem with this line:

```
<div class="TrescPotwierdzTresc">@Model.Article</div>
```

The problem is with "br" tag inside @Model.Article wont work. I can see this tag after page load, but text is still in the same line. WHen i do something like this:

```
<div class="TrescPotwierdzTresc">@Model.Tresc br @Model.Tresc</div>
```

The br tag between "@Model.Tresc" elements work fine. Do You have any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: You need to show us what's inside @Model.Article and also tell us what templating system you're using.

Comment: It is Razor obviously

Comment: Inside @Model.Article is "public string Article { get; set; }", and to bind this string i'am using simple ado.net code: SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    model.Article = rdr["Article"].ToString();
                    model.Autor = rdr["Autor"].ToString();
                    model.Data = rdr["Data"].ToString();
                    model.zdjecieLink = rdr["LinkZdjecie"].ToString();
                    model.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"].ToString());
                }
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="TrescPotwierdzTresc">@Html.Raw(Model.Article)</div>
```

`Html.Raw` returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: Ok, thanks for eplain. I will accept answer soon, Thank You for help, it works fine !

Comment: By default ASP.NET encodes all HTML entities due to security reasons. So your `<br>` tags look like `&lt;br&gt;`. `Html.Raw` decodes them so that browsers can render them correctly.

Comment: @Null Reference, please add your warning as a comment under the answer.

Comment: Caution: Html.Raw should be used with caution since it may lead to [cross site scripting] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7751180/3186681). As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)Html.Raw() is a Medium trust for the immediate caller. This member can be used by partially trusted code.