# MVC html.raw producing "An error occurred while processing your request"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC application, my /Views/Content/Details.cshtml page has the following:

```
@model example.Models.Content

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
```

This works as expected. The web browser produces the data in the "Description" column from the SQL database.

For testing purposes, I configured an entry in the Description column with the following data:

```
<p>This is a test</p>
```

The Web Browser displays `<p>This is a test</p>`, which is to say that the Web Browser is displaying the markup.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751148/what-does-html-raw-do) and [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1904870.aspx?Html%20Raw%20doesn%20t%20work%20with%20HTML%20DisplayFor%20) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027683/html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view) mention that `@Html.Raw(model.Description)` should resolve this issue. I revised my code to this:

```
@model example.Models.Content

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@Html.Raw(model.Description)
```

The Web Browser now produces "An error occurred while processing your request". I am certain I must be overlooking something simple here, but I am just not seeing the cause of the problem.

Comment: try to use  `@Html.Raw(Model.Description)` instead of `@Html.Raw(model.Description)`  capital `M` in for `Model`..
Hope  it resolve your issue ..

Comment: Oh my, I did not know that this was CaSe SenSiTiVe. Thank you very much @SunilKumar. If you want to submit this as an answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using small `m` for binding `Model` as in asp.net MVC the Model bindings are case sensitive You have to you your code as following way :
Use :

`@Html.Raw(Model.Description)`

instead of using

`@Html.Raw(model.Description)`

You have to use Capital `M` for binding your Model.

Thanks